# Integer to POSIXlt

Tags: r, posixlt

I'm starting to get a handle on how base R handles dates/times, but still have some uncertainty.

Using the following data set (exert from meteorological data), I was able to convert to POSIXct and POSIXlt using the `as.character()` function.  The Date.Time is provided in the format yymmddhhmm.

```
Date.Time <- c(1107151300, 1107151400, 1107151500, 1107151600, 1107151700, 1107151800)
WindSpd <-   c(11.8, 14.5, 14.9, 14.1, 15.2, 17.1)

##Using as.character()##
#Note POSIXlt this time
w <- data.frame(Date.Time, WindSpd)
w$Date.Time <- as.POSIXlt(as.character(w$Date.Time), format = '%y%m%d%H%M', 
origin = '2011-07-15 13:00:00')
w

#Now POSIXct
x <- data.frame(Date.Time, WindSpd)
x$Date.Time <- as.POSIXct(as.character(x$Date.Time), format = '%y%m%d%H%M', 
origin = '2011-07-15 13:00:00')
x
```

However, it seems silly to convert integers to characters in the sake of converting to a date.  When I try to convert the integers directly, I get all NA values.

```
##Trying to coerce the intergers##
#note POSIXlt this time
y <- data.frame(Date.Time, WindSpd)
y$Date.Time <- as.POSIXlt(y$Date.Time, format = '%y%m%d%H%M', 
origin = '2011-07-15 13:00:00')
y

#note POSIXct this time
z <- data.frame(Date.Time, WindSpd)
z$Date.Time <- as.POSIXct(z$Date.Time, format = '%y%m%d%H%M', 
origin = '2011-07-15 13:00:00')
z
```

Obviously this isn't a crucial problem, as I've found a working solution.  I would like to know anyways, as I'm trying to become a betteR codeR.  What am I doing wrong in converting the integers to the R date classes?  Also, are their benefits associated with `POSIXlt` vs `POSIXct`?  According to the help article, it sounds like the only difference is how they are stored?

Comment: How are you reading in the data?

Comment: Do not use POSIXlt in dataframes. The list substructure of that class gets messed up by other functions when accessed from within dataframes. Go back to the beginning and use POSIXct.

Comment: The original data is a tab delimited text file.  I'm reading it in with `sageW <- read.table('sagebrushW.txt', header = TRUE, sep = '\t')`

Comment: @DWin Do you mean use my second option of with `as.POSIXct` and `as.character`, or start over using `as.POSIXct`?

Comment: You need to sue it with as.character to prevent the `as.POSIXct.numeric method` from being dispatched.

Comment: You can read in with `colClasses` specified in `read.table` to get it into character initially.

Comment: @DWin perhaps you'd better expand your comment and make it an answer? I'd always wondered why people were so against `POSIXlt`. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an `as.POSIXct.numeric` method:

```
 > methods(as.POSIXct)
[1] as.POSIXct.date    as.POSIXct.Date    as.POSIXct.dates   as.POSIXct.default
[5] as.POSIXct.numeric as.POSIXct.POSIXlt
```

It uses numeric input as the number of seconds offset from the origin.

```
> as.POSIXct(1107151300, origin = '2011-07-15 13:00:00')
[1] "2046-08-14 19:01:40 PDT"
> as.POSIXct('1107151300', format = '%y%m%d%H%M', 
                          origin = '2011-07-15 13:00:00')
[1] "2011-07-15 13:00:00 PDT"
```

So, yes, you do need to use `as.character`.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the format spec (I believe it is only needed for character input):

```
zz <- as.POSIXct(Date.Time, origin = '2011-07-15 13:00:00')
```

It will work if you supply Date.Time as time in actual seconds from '2011-07-15 13:00:00' with the correct time zone

Comment: How extensively did you test this answer?

Comment: I just ran it as `as.POSIXct(as.integer(Sys.time()), origin = '1970-01-01 00:00:00')`. Gave me what I was looking for.

Comment: I was hoping that could be your `moment of Zen` but can you now try: `as.POSIXct(1107151300, origin = '2011-07-15 13:00:00')` and see if you can understand our concern.

Comment: I did before, and I got exactly the same thing as you. I agree that there is no way R will process yymmddhhmm as if it were a numeric and give you the answer as posed in the original question.