# R warning: "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length" seems incorrect

Tags: arrays, r, list, vector, variable-assignment

I have an example R script that looks like this:

```
# Create example data
date <- c("11/09/2016", "11/02/2016", "11/16/2016", "11/23/2016")
column_two <- c(4, 2, 3, 4)
# Populate a data frame and make sure the dates have the correct class
mydata <- data.frame(date, column_two)
mydata$date <- strptime(mydata$date, format="%m/%d/%Y")

print("The contents of mydata are:")
print(mydata)

# Create a dummy list (or vector, or array, or what is it?)
foo <- rep(NA, 5)
print("foo is initialized to:")
print(foo)
print("The class of foo is:")
print(class(foo))

earlydate <- min(mydata$date)
print(sprintf("Earliest date is: %s", earlydate))
print("The class of earlydate is:")
print(class(earlydate))
print(sprintf("Length of earliest date is: %d", length(earlydate)))
print(sprintf("Length of foo[2] is: %d", length(foo[2])))

# Attempt to set one variable equal to another
foo[2] <- earlydate

print("After assignment, foo looks like this:")
print(foo)
print("Now the classes of foo, foo[2], and foo[[2]] are:")
print(class(foo))
print(class(foo[2]))
print(class(foo[[2]]))
```

The printed output from the script looks like this:

```
> source("test_warning.R")
[1] "The contents of mydata are:"
        date column_two
1 2016-11-09          4
2 2016-11-02          2
3 2016-11-16          3
4 2016-11-23          4
[1] "foo is initialized to:"
[1] NA NA NA NA NA
[1] "The class of foo is:"
[1] "logical"
[1] "Earliest date is: 2016-11-02"
[1] "The class of earlydate is:"
[1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt" 
[1] "Length of earliest date is: 1"
[1] "Length of foo[2] is: 1"
[1] "After assignment, foo looks like this:"
[[1]]
[1] NA

[[2]]
[1] 0

[[3]]
[1] NA

[[4]]
[1] NA

[[5]]
[1] NA

[1] "Now the classes of foo, foo[2], and foo[[2]] are:"
[1] "list"
[1] "list"
[1] "numeric"
Warning message:
In foo[2] <- earlydate :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
>
```

I have so many questions:

- Why do I get a warning when `foo[2]` and `earlydate` are manifestly the same length?
- Why is the value of foo[2] set to `0` rather than to the value of `earlydate`?
- It's obvious that R is automatically coercing the `foo` variable and its elements into new classes; why don't any of those classes (for `foo`, or `foo[2]`, or `foo[[2]]`) seem to match the class (`"POSIXlt" "POSIXt"`) of the `earlydate` variable?
- How would I initialize `foo` correctly so that it becomes a vector, or list, or array-like thing containing individual elements which are capable of supporting this type of value assignment without raising the warning and resulting in this type of counter-intuitive behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Well, behind the scenes of `POSIXlt` is actually a list.

```
> class(unclass(earlydate))
[1] "list"
> length(unclass(earlydate))
[1] 11
```

The assignment takes 0 because that's the first element of the list; it's the count of seconds and is 0 for `earlydate`.

```
> unclass(earlydate)[1]
$sec
[1] 0
```

I don't really know why R doesn't automatically coerce the `foo` variable into the `POSIXlt` class; my guess is that coercion to dates in general is hard. It's clear what to do here where all of `foo` is `NA`, but what if one of the elements is already an integer or a string? But to coerce it yourself first, use `as.POSIXlt`.

```
foo <- rep(as.POSIXlt(NA), 5)
```

Depending what else you'll be doing with it, you may also find using `POSIXct` to be better solution, as discussed in this answer to [Integer to POSIXlt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17414294/210673). It stores the date as number of seconds since the origin, so is not a list underneath and so is better suited for certain kinds of computation and storage.